# OnEvent cast incorrect event Object using EventBus

Tags: android, android-fragments, greenrobot-eventbus

I have register `EventBus` on both `Activity (BaseActivity)` and `Fragment (BaseFragment)`. So, I catch event with:
In `BaseActivity`, and `BaseFragment` I have same code:

```
public void onEvent(Object object) {
    // do nothing
}
```

In my child `fragment (A)` `extended` from `BaseFragment`, I have a event for it `XYZEvent`, and I expected that this method is called:

```
public void onEvent(XYZEvent event) {
    // my logic, not called :(
}
```

But it did not. I have debugged, both onEvent in `BaseActivity` and `BaseFragment` are called. 
So, I changed my `fragment (A)` like below:

```
public void onEvent(Object event) {
   if(event instanceof XYZEvent) {
       // my logic
       // after changed this block code is called (~_~), why???
   }
}
```

It's called.
So, I want to know what am I missed when `onEvent(XYZEvent event)` not fired? but `onEvent(Object event)` did. Seem returned event has wrong casting, my `XYZEvent` was casted to `Object`.

P/S: I used this library `compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'` and XYZEvent contains an `Serializable` object

Comment: What I would guess is the event is pass with a casting to force the parameter to be an Object (strange but should explains this). So on call, `onEvent((Object)event)` would take the closest definition to `onEvent(Object)`, the one from BaseFragment. This need to be checked

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the event is `XYZEvent` why closest to `Object` here? Also, if I test by commented out `onEvent(Object event)` in `BaseActivity` and `BaseFragment`, my `onEvent(XYZEvent event)` still not fired. The only way to make it called is `onEvent(Object event)`.

Comment: I don't have an Environnement to search but using debugger to find the source of the call, and check the source code, you should find it. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26844295/4391450), this might help you ;)

Comment: @AxelH After try debug again, I found that `onEvent(XYZEvent event` not in `subscriptions` list. I don't know why? If I remove all `onEvent(object)` my `XYZEvent` still not in `subscriptions` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is my mistake. I have a onEvent method in service, it already steal my XYZEvent.